# LINQ EntityFramework, sort by the attributes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following data structure. 
[image: Data Structure]

I would like to give the query method an `AttributeId` and it should then sort the `List of vehicles` by the value of this `AttributeId`.

For example, if two vehicles both have an attribute with the id 123 and vehicle1 has the value "cdf" and vehicle2 has the value "abc" and I pass 123 to the method it should return a list of vehicles with the vehicle2 first and then the vehicle1.

The whole query method is working but I'm just struggling with the sorting. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

This is the basic query I have right now:

```
var query = (from v in context.Vehicles
    //left join vehicleAttributes
    join va in context.VehicleAttributes on v.VehicleId equals va.VehicleId into vAttributes
    from vehicleAttributes in vAttributes.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where v.FleetId == fleetId
    select new { v, vehicleAttributes });
```

EDIT: 
I should have mentioned this before, I of course tried a simple order by vehicleAttributes.Value but since every vehicle can have multiple vehicleattributes I somehow need to specify to order the query by the value of the attributeId I pass to the query.

Comment: check my post it will help you

Comment: Do you want to return all attributes or just attributes with id that you pass into the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from v in context.Vehicles

                         //left join vehicleAttributes
                         join va in context.VehicleAttributes on v.VehicleId equals va.VehicleId into vAttributes
                         from vehicleAttributes in vAttributes.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         where v.FleetId == fleetId
                         orderby vehicleAttributes.Value ascending 
                         select new { v, vehicleAttributes });
```

Comment: this won't work since a vehicle can have multiple vehicle attributes and i somehow need to specify that it should order it by the value of the attributeId i pass to the method

Answer (score 0):

You need `orderby`

```
var query = (from v in context.Vehicles
              join va in context.VehicleAttributes on v.VehicleId equals va.VehicleId 
              where v.FleetId == fleetId
              orderby va.Value ascending
              select new { Id = v.FleetId, Value = va.Value, Date = v.DateCreated });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand how this would work, considering that AttributeId is a primary key and hence unique. However, I think this should be enough for you to find your way. BTW, you can make your queries much cleaner by using Navigation Properties. I defined the following one:

```
 public class Vehicle
    {
        [Key]
        public int VehicleId { get; set; }

        public int FleetId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<VehicleAttribute> VehicleAttributes { get; set; }
    }


int fleetId = 1;
int attributeId = 1;
var q = from v in ctx.Vehicles
    where v.FleetId == fleetId
    select
        new
        {
            v.VehicleId,
            v.VehicleAttributes,
            SortingAttribute = v.VehicleAttributes.FirstOrDefault(va => va.AttributeId == attributeId)
        }
    into output
    orderby output.SortingAttribute.Value descending
    select output;
```